# AppStore style scroll effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

[Update] Ive added some content inset to my table view. So is it possible to add a view in the gap that is created ?

What I want to achieve is the following scroll effect :

Open the AppStore on the iPhone and go to the Featured tab.

1. Swipe down : Only the table view scrolls down, the banner with images stays fixed
2. Swipe up : Everything including the banner view moves up.

My initial thoughts were that there is a table view inside a scroll view but Apple advises against doing that ...

My second attempt was to use a table header view, but the header view would scroll both ways.

So what kind of tweaking has to be done to UITableViewController to achieve this effect ?

What I have so far :

[image]

What I need is basically [this](http://mohit.athwani.net/KSMX.gif)

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/ this will help you

Answer (score 0):

For example :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 ){
        CGRect frame = self.myView.frame;
        frame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y ;
        self.myView.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

It's the idea !

Comment: yes it's! I made this "effect" for most of my views with `UIScrolView`

Comment: change `myView` to `tableView.tableHeaderView` if you want keep the tableHeaderView on the top when your are scrolling down

Comment: I will go ahead and try this out ... But just for reference, what I actually need is the effect in this link : http://mohit.athwani.net/KSMX.gif

Comment: I started off with a completely clean table view controller and tried your solution ... My code is available on https://www.copy.com/s/Bb0AFrGssvJ9EOAa/KSM_Code.png and the outcome is available on : https://www.copy.com/s/KZodVG6K1KuNtzGq/KSM.gif ... thanks for your patience :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60235/discussion-between-mohit-athwani-and-nicolas-bonnet).

Answer (score 0):

They used `sections` nothing fancy.

You'll want to use:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Try returning a `UIView` for the `viewForHeaderInSection` and it will give you the same as the App Store Features tab.

Comment: I did it once it does give the effect. Did you set the height of the view as high as your example?